# How to find a function $f$ that satisfy the equation $f(x)=f(x-1)+x^2$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

How to find a continuous function $f$ that satisfy the equation $f(x)=f(x-1)+x^2$

Where both $x$ and $f$ are members of the set of real numbers.

There’s probably more than one $f$ that satisfies the equation. So is there like a general form for all $f$ that do so?

Comment: For _any_ function on $[0,1)$, you can use the relation to define a function $f$ on all of $\Bbb R$. So when you say "there's probably many", well, yes, you're quite right.

Comment: Did you want to assume continuity or anything like that?

Comment: Then please edit your post to indicate that.

Comment: Note:  you can find cubic polynomials that work, just for example.  And, if $f(x)$ works then so does $f(x)+c$ for any constant $c$.

Comment: @lulu yes i would like it to be a continuous function. In fact let me update the question.

Comment: That looks a lot like the sum of the first  $n$ perfect squares. Here's the equation for that: $f(n)=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$

Comment: @lulu. That’s smart. Thanks a lot. Is there a way to generalize all continuous functions that would satisfy the equation. The cubic function you suggested does satisfy it but seems like something you got from intuition. Is there a way to perhaps work out functions that also satisfies it from scratch.

Comment: Any such $f$ takes the form $f(x)=\frac{x(x+1)(2x+1)}{6}+g(x)$ where $g$ is a continuous periodic function with period $1$.

Comment: I got it by noting that the sum of squares function on the integers obviously satisfies this.  That's a cubic polynomial.

Comment: I have suppressed the tag "recreational mathematics" which had nothing to do here.

Comment: No problem, I’ve removed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is similar to the function that gives the sum of the first $n$ perfect squares. It actually follows from how that formula is proved by induction.

In this case then $f(x)=\dfrac{x(x+1)(2x+1)}{6}$

This is because for example: $f(3)-f(2)=3^2$ which should fit that sum of squares description.

However, it doesn't hurt to be more detailed. Let's say the $x^2$ defines a polynomial function. I think this is the only kind of function possible but I can't prove it.

Let's also pick one of degree 3. I'll explain why in the end.

Define it generally as $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$

Then:

$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=f(x)=a(x-1)^3+b(x-1)^2+c(x-1)+d+x^2$

Let me just do the messy expansion for you.

$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=ax^3+(b-3a+1)x^2+(3a-2b+c)x+(b+d-c-a)$

Equating coefficients we have:

$c=3a-2b+c \implies 3a=2b$

$b=b-3a+1 \implies a=\dfrac{1}{3}$

$b=3 \cdot \dfrac{1}{3} \cdot \dfrac{1}{2}=\dfrac{1}{2}$

$d=b+d-c-a \implies c=\dfrac{1}{6}$

$d$ is not determined so in the function it can be anything.

Thus all functions satisfying this equation are:

$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{3}x^3+\dfrac{1}{2}x^2+\dfrac{1}{6}x+d$

Or when you factorize and add elegance:

$\boxed{f(x)=\dfrac{x(x+1)(2x+1)}{6}+k \quad k \in \mathbb{R}}$

The reason why I picked a cubic is because upon expansion, the $ax^3$ terms cancel out as the working shows. That's why I didn't consider them. In that case the next lowest power which is $bx^2$ needs to match the highest power on the other side. So we don't need to go any higher than 3.

$\text{Edit}^2$
I hear that in this case $k$ can also be a function with a period of one e.g. $\sin(2\pi x)$ @ WE Tutorial School. Why didn't I think of that? Anyway, the other backbone is legitimate reasoning.

I also tried adding a higher power $ex^4$ on $f(x)$ but I got $a=a-4e$ which gives me a stronger statement.